# The "create new ec2 instance" wizard is not allowing me to select existing Security Groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I have a carefully crafted and secure Default Security Group that should be used for this new `ec2` instance. However none of my existing SG's are included in the `Configure Security Group` screen. Instead two new ones are shown that are worse than useless

[image]

Port 80 open to the world ??

[image]

Why are my existing security group's not displayed?  Note I have checked the Region is the correct one containing the properly constructed SG's.

Comment: SGs are VPC specific. So you only see SGs from the VPC where you place your instance.

Comment: @Marcin  Thanks - i had tried the "default" but turns out it were a different one. Feel free to make an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments.

Security groups (SGs) are **VPC specific**. Thus, the issue was caused by launching an instance in a different VPC then intended. Subsequently, expected SGs were not available for the instance.

The **solution** was to use correct VPC.